# Декодирование URL в Sublime Text 3

Tags: url, sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Здравствуйте. Имеются файлы, где содержится множество URL и прочего текста. Необходимо декодировать в них все ссылки вида `http://kristinita.ru/404_files/%D0%9D%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85.jpg` на `http://kristinita.ru/404_files/На_свадьбе_знакомых.jpg` . Как это осуществить быстро и корректно, чтобы ненароком не удалить лишнего? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Неправильное решение

Установить плагин [StringEncode](https://github.com/colinta/SublimeStringEncode) и открыв файл, где требуется декодировать URL, выполнить  `Edit` → `StringEncode` → `URL Decode` . В таком случае символ `+` заменится на пробел во всём тексте, включая уже раскодированные адреса.

[image: Удаление плюса при декодировке URL в StringEncode]

Разработчик [не собирается](https://github.com/colinta/SublimeStringEncode/issues/26#issuecomment-210067563) исправлять данный баг. На мою реплику   «seriously do much harm» он возразил «[this is very melodramatic](https://github.com/colinta/SublimeStringEncode/issues/26#issuecomment-210075136)». К счастью, пользуюсь плагином [Local History](https://github.com/vishr/local-history): откатился к старым версиям файлов, у которых плагин удалил плюсы.

По той же причине не рекомендуется пользоваться некоторыми онлайн-декодерами, например, расположенными на сайтах [MeyerWeb](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) и [FreeFormatter](http://www.freeformatter.com/url-encoder.html#ad-output).

Автор плагина [советовал](https://github.com/colinta/SublimeStringEncode/issues/26#issuecomment-210067563) использовать при работе с плагином StringEncode регулярное выражение `https?://\S+`:

[image: Декодирование только URL через StringEncode]

Несмотря на то, что шаблон может находить адреса вроде `http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_philosophy/902/%D0%9F%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%94%D0%98%D0%93%D0%9C%D0%90"><font`, декодирование происходит корректно. Однако если в URL уже присутствуют плюсы, они удалятся, почему и этот вариант неудовлетворительный.

#### Правильное решение

Плагин [URLEncode](https://github.com/mastahyeti/URLEncode). Шорткаты декодировки URL: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. Вроде бы ничего лишнего не сносится.

[image: Пример работы URLEncode]

#### Альтернативное решение

Универсальное, не зависящее от текстового редактора — онлайн-сервис http://www.urldecoder.org. Вероятно, если проверять и тестировать, можно также отыскать другие его корректно функционирующие аналоги.